# How to convert between a Unicode/UCS codepoint and a UTF16 surrogate pair?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++14, surrogate-pairs, ucs

How to convert back and forth between a Unicode/UCS codepoint and a UTF16 surrogate pair in C++14 and later?

**EDIT:** Removed mention of UCS-2 surrogates, as there is no such thing. Thanks [@remy-lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11 and later, you can use [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) to convert between various UTF/UCS encodings, using the following [`std::codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) types:

- UTF-8 <-> UCS-2:
  [`std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8)
- UTF-8 <-> UTF-16:
  [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16)
- UTF-8 <-> UTF-32/UCS-4:
  [`std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8)
- UCS-2 <-> UTF-16:
  [`std::codecvt_utf16<char16_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16)
- UTF-16 <-> UTF-32/UCS-4:
  [`std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16)
- UCS-2 <-> UTF-32/UCS-4:
  no standard conversion, but you can write your own `std::codecvt` class for it if needed.  Otherwise, use one of the above conversions in between:
  `UCS-2 <-> UTF-X <-> UTF-32/UCS-4`

You don't need to handle surrogates manually.

You can use [`std::u32string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to hold your codepoint(s), and [`std::u16string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to hold your UTF-16/UCS-2 codeunits.

For example:

```
using convert_utf16_uf32 = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t>, char16_t>;

std::u16string CodepointToUTF16(const char32_t codepoint)
{
    const char32_t *p = &codepoint;
    return convert_utf16_uf32{}.from_bytes(
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(p),
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(p+1)
    );
}

std::u16string UTF32toUTF16(const std::u32string &str)
{
    return convert_utf16_uf32{}.from_bytes(
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str.data()),
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str.data()+str.size())
    );
}

char32_t UTF16toCodepoint(const std::u16string &str)
{
    std::string bytes = convert_utf16_uf32{}.to_bytes(str);
    return *(reinterpret_cast<const char32_t*>(bytes.data()));
}

std::u32string UTF16toUTF32(const std::u16string &str)
{
    std::string bytes = convert_utf16_uf32{}.to_bytes(str);
    return std::u32string(
       reinterpret_cast<const char32_t*>(bytes.data()),
       bytes.size() / sizeof(char32_t)
    );
}
```

Comment: The example to convert strings is helpful, but please provide the essential example to convert single codepoints as well.

Comment: Additionally, according to cppreference.com the `std::codecvt_`-prefixed classes seem to be deprecated in C++17. Any comment on that?

Comment: @jotik i updated my answer with single-codepoint examples. I have no idea why they are deprecated in C++17 or what they are being replaced with.

Comment: @jotik from [std::wstring_convert and std::codecvt_utf8 deprecated](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/5yo0el/stdwstring_convert_and_stdcodecvt_utf8_deprecated/): "*In the history of the cppreference.com page there's a note that **"p0618r0 deprecated codecvt". This paper is not publicly available so we don't know what it says**.*"

Comment: It's available now

Comment: @Cubbi: I see that now (http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html), but it still does not describe what `<codecvt>`, `std::wstring_convert`, and `std:::wbuffer_convert` are being replaced with, if anything, only that they are to be deprecated (and apparently the [committee did adopt p0618r0](https://isocpp.org/blog/2017/03/2017-03-post-kona-mailing-available): "*Adopted 2017-03*").

Comment: @RemyLebeau they aren't being replaced, they are being deprecated to encourage future replacement  (and I think it's begging to repeat std::strstream's fate)

Answer (score 8):

The [surrogate-pairs](/questions/tagged/surrogate-pairs) tag [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-pairs/info) explains (better than specified by the [Unicode Standard 9.0](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/UnicodeStandard-9.0.pdf) in §3.9, Table 3-5.) the algorithm to convert from codepoint to surrogate pair as follows:

> Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, that is characters with code above 0xFFFF, are encoded in UTF-16 by pairs of 16-bit code units called surrogate pairs, by the following scheme:
>
> - 0x010000 is subtracted from the code point, leaving a 20-bit number in the range 0..0x0FFFFF;
> - the top ten bits (a number in the range 0..0x03FF) are added to 0xD800 to give the first code unit or high surrogate, which will be in the range 0xD800..0xDBFF;
> - the low ten bits (also in the range 0..0x03FF) are added to 0xDC00 to give the second code unit or low surrogate, which will be in the range 0xDC00..0xDFFF.

In C++14 and later this could be written as:

```
#include <cstdint>

using codepoint = std::uint32_t;
using utf16 = std::uint16_t;

struct surrogate {
    utf16 high; // Leading
    utf16 low;  // Trailing
};

constexpr surrogate split(codepoint const in) noexcept {
    auto const inMinus0x10000 = (in - 0x10000);
    surrogate const r{
            static_cast<utf16>((inMinus0x10000 / 0x400) + 0xd800), // High
            static_cast<utf16>((inMinus0x10000 % 0x400) + 0xdc00)}; // Low
    return r;
}
```

In the reverse direction one just has to combine the last 10 bits from the high surrogate and the last 10 bits from the low surrogate, and add `0x10000`:

```
constexpr codepoint combine(surrogate const s) noexcept {
    return static_cast<codepoint>(
            ((s.high - 0xd800) * 0x400) + (s.low - 0xdc00) + 0x10000);
}
```

Here's a test for these conversions:

```
#include <cassert>

constexpr bool isValidUtf16Surrogate(utf16 v) noexcept
{ return (v & 0xf800) == 0xd800; }

constexpr bool isValidCodePoint(codepoint v) noexcept {
    return (v <= 0x10ffff)
        && ((v >= 0x10000) || !isValidUtf16Surrogate(static_cast<utf16>(v)));
}

constexpr bool isValidUtf16HighSurrogate(utf16 v) noexcept
{ return (v & 0xfc00) == 0xd800; }

constexpr bool isValidUtf16LowSurrogate(utf16 v) noexcept
{ return (v & 0xfc00) == 0xdc00; }

constexpr bool codePointNeedsUtf16Surrogates(codepoint v) noexcept
{ return (v >= 0x10000) && (v <= 0x10ffff); }

void test(codepoint const in) {
    assert(isValidCodePoint(in));
    assert(codePointNeedsUtf16Surrogates(in));
    auto const s = split(in);
    assert(isValidUtf16HighSurrogate(s.high));
    assert(isValidUtf16LowSurrogate(s.low));
    auto const out = combine(s);
    assert(isValidCodePoint(out));
    assert(in == out);
}

int main() {
    for (codepoint c = 0x10000; c <= 0x10ffff; ++c)
        test(c);
}
```