# Why a regular expression is valid in Java, but not in C++

Tags: c++, regex, unicode

I use the following regular expression to remove emojis:

```
"[\ud83c\udc00-\ud83c\udfff]|[\ud83d\udc00-\ud83d\udfff]|[\u2600-\u27ff]"
```

it works well in Java. But I got compile errors in c++:

> \ud83c is not a valid Unicode character
>   \udc00 is not a valid Unicode character
>   \ud83c is not a valid Unicode character
>   \udfff is not a valid Unicode character
>   \ud83d is not a valid Unicode character
>   \udc00 is not a valid Unicode character
>   \ud83d is not a valid Unicode character
>   \udfff is not a valid Unicode character

How do I use the regular expression in c++?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: And aren't most of those codepoints part of utf-16 surrogate pairs? They're not valid by themselves, so the warnings make sense if you're using a utf-8 encoding.

Comment: In Java, `\u` defines a code unit, but in C++, `\u` defines a code point.

Comment: Raw strings are also the way to go for regex in C++

Comment: That only matches a few emojis. Better regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58718505/46395

Comment: Also, Java strings are Unicode.  In C++, to use `\u` characters, make sure you are using a Unicode `wchar_t`/`char16_t`/`char32_t` string, not an ANSI `char` string (unless you are using UTF-8 and a regex parser that supports UTF-8)